# keyCode for tab is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

I am using the event keypress in backbone. The keyCode for Enter(13) works fine but the keyCode for tab(9) is not working for some odd reason. Please help me figure this out. Thanks.

```
onEnterSetTitle: function(ev) {
        if (ev.keyCode === 9) {
            this.$el.find('.set-title-input input').trigger('blur');
        }
    },
```

Comment: Try `ev.which`. What browser are you testing.

Comment: Try doing ev.preventDefault to prevent the default behavior. inside the IF..

Comment: I am using Chrome but also tested in IE11. the tab key still acts like default even with ev.preventDefault().

Comment: you want to use `ev.key === "Tab"` [(src)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values#whitespace_keys), `ev.keyCode` is now deprecated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed it by replace keypress with keydown.

Comment: keypress() captures only printable chars, while keydown() captures all, including tab.

Answer (score 0):

if i have to do this then i would use `||` operator this way:

```
onEnterSetTitle: function(ev) {
    var kc = ev.which || ev.keyCode;
    if (kc === 9) {
        .........
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `ev.which` sufficient? I thought that was jQuery's way of getting the keyCode cross-browser. http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: yes that would be sufficient but on firefox (some older version browsers of it) i got some of the things not worked as intended then on stackoverflow itself i found this style of doing and it worked for me that point of time.

Comment: i tried with ev.which and with the ev.preventDefault but it's still not triggering the blur event.